# Is there a method for clearing out the contents in a csv file before appending data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, fs

I want to overwrite or clear out the contents in a csv file before I append new data. Is there a method for this ?

Comment: are you using node?

Comment: So you want the file to be empty before writing?

Comment: @baao Yup exactly

Comment: @TimCodes Yea im using node. Specifically the fs npm package to append data

Comment: could just overwirte file or try fs.unlink()

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlink_path_callback

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a new file, and overwrite the old file on saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write to the file using fs.writeFile, it will override an existing file (if one exists).

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('message.csv', 'new content', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```